# Intellij Idea 13 configuration. Navigating between methods

Tags: intellij-idea

Where do I find the checkbox to navigate between methods?

Example: inside one tab going into one method pressing then Alt+Navigation Key I want return back or up. Currently Alt+Navigation Key get me to previous opened Tab.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same Problem. By default 13 will open without the Toolbar.

Go to `View --> Toolbar` and enable Toolbar. It will enable the tool bar you need.
Or you can use `ctrl+Alt+Left` to go to previous method

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Navigate->Back/Forward. You can get the keystroke from the menu items.

[image]

Comment: At work I have Intellij Idea 12, without any additional configuration I always navigate with Alt + Navigation Key. Although in this menu Back/Forward are mapped to Ctrl + Alt + Navigation Key.

Answer (score 0):

Seems long time ago I have changed Idea keymap for this at work.
Open Settings->Keymap, find there in tree Main menu-> Navigate -> and change Back / Forward to Alt + Navigation Key.
P.S. I was searching for combination Alt+Left/Alt+Right, but Idea doesn't search this way (